# UniqueCheck on super classes in PlayFramework?

Tags: playframework

I saw the UniqueCheck being added on 1.2.4. Which is really great! 
Howerer, I'm experiencing some kind of problems with it using it on Super-classes and implementation classes.

An example will be better than a long post :

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
abstract class Utilisateur extends Model {

    @Unique
    public String email;
..
}
```

And two implementations Candidat & Entreprise both extending Utilisateur.

You cannot add two Candidat having the same email, neither can you add two Entreprise having the same email. 
But you can have a Candidat user having the same email as the Entreprise user!

I decided to digg a bit deeper and discovered this :

```
select count(entreprise0_.id) as col_0_0_ from Entreprise entreprise0_ inner join Utilisateur entreprise0_1_ on entreprise0_.id=entreprise0_1_.id where entreprise0_1_.email=? limit ?
```

The UniqueCheck is based upon a select count query.

Which seems ok but shouldn't it take in account super classes?

Any ideas how to bypass this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid the source code doesn't cover your scenario (unless I misread it). Somehow it makes sense as even if the entities share some details in the database, from the point of view of the program they are different classes and different categories of objects. The fact that they have a common parent doesn't mean they share restrictions (think about Animal, Bird and Dog. Only 1 can fly)

The only alternative I see is to implement your own validator following either [this](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/validation#custom) or [this other](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/validation#customannotations) template. In it you can just run a SQL query against the database and decide.

Something like:

```
  Candidat.count(
    "select c from Candidat c, Enterprise e where c.email like (?1) and e.email = c.email", email);
```

(warning: from memory query, can't test it now, it may have some typo!)

That should do it :)